# Crystal Reports: Formula for when all parameter selections are selected

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with just two selections for users - ambulance and medic. If a user selects both selections, the report should display, "Ambulance and Medic Response." It sounds easy, but I just can't seem to figure this one out. Right now I have,

```
if {?Parameter} in ['Ambulance', 'Medic'] Then....
```

But the report says the array must be subscribed. How do I do this? Is there a way around not using the array?

---

And there was a way! Someone just pointed me to the right path.

```
StringVar title := '';
NumberVar i := 1;
While i <= ubound({?Parameter}) Do
(
If title = '' then 
title := {?Parameter}[i]
else
title := title + ' and ' + {?Parameter}[i];
i := i + 1;
);
title + ' Response';
```

Comment: Please close this one.

Answer (score 1):

This simpler expression should do the same:

```
Join({?Parameter}, ' and ')  + ' Response'
```